# How can i link two fields from one field in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Sorry for my english.

**Question**: How can I link this?

```
{tbl_assignment_request.new_employee_code} = {tbl_employee.employee_code} and
{tbl_assignment_request.old_employee_code} = {tbl_employee.employee_code}
```

When I select that, crystal report is displaying blank? 
Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options:

1- is having on main report your tables linked by

`{tbl_assignment_request.new_employee_code} = {tbl_employee.employee_code}`

and a `subreport` linked by

```
{tbl_assignment_request.old_employee_code} = {tbl_employee.employee_code}
```

2- nothing on main report and crate 2 `subreports` with those links